# How to write the following string ?

Tags: javascript, json, string, mathjax

I want to write the following string, but it gives the error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
var str=" <span class="math-tex"> /( /sum /) </span> "; 
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Please start with a basic tutorial such as http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript  - your error isin your use of "

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to escape the quotes within the declaration of the string.

```
var str=" <span class=\"math-tex\"> /( /sum /) </span> "; 
console.log(str);
```

Or use single quotes.

```
var str=" <span class='math-tex'> /( /sum /) </span> "; 
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes. It fails because your input string contains double quotes and the quotes you actually used to assign that string to a variable is also double quotes. So when the interpreter sees the second double quotes, it would consider that point as end of the string.

```
var str= ' <span class="math-tex"> /( /sum /) </span> ';
```